# get_random_bytes() equivalent in Solaris

Tags: c, random, kernel, solaris, kernel-module

[Linux](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1253) and [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+4.9-RELEASE&format=html) offer a nice interface to the RNG to be used from the kernel:

```
 void get_random_bytes(void *buf, int nbytes);
```

since a KMD can't easily open a device file. I'm however unable to find anything similar in the Solaris' [Kernel functions for drivers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5180/6mbbf01o6/index.html).

What is the intended way for a kernel module in Solaris to get CS random numbers (i.e. those you'd get from `/dev/urandom` in usermode)?

Comment: There's a good discussion of Solaris kernel random number generation here:  https://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/solaris_random_number_generation  The old OpenSolaris source code for the kernel functions `random_get_pseudo_bytes()`, `random_get_bytes()`, and `random_get_blocking_bytes()` can be found here:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/crypto/api/kcf_random.c#1100

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You probably should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, there's a good discussion of Solaris kernel random number generation here: https://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/solaris_random_number_generation

> There is a single kernel module (random) for implementing both the
>   /dev/random and /dev/urandom devices. The two primary entry points are
>   rnd_read() and rnd_write() for servicing read(2) and write(2) system
>   calls respectively.
>
> rnd_read() calls either kcf_rnd_get_bytes() or
>   kcf_rnd_get_pseudo_bytes() depending on wither the device node is an
>   instance of /dev/random or /dev/urandom respectively. In FIPS mode, if
>   /dev/random has been opened for nonblocking reads (neither O_NBLOCK
>   nor O_NDELAY set), the rnd_read call will call fips_random_get_bytes()
>   There is a cap on the maximum number of bytes that can be transfered
>   in a single read, MAXRETBYTES_RANDOM (1040) and
>   MAXRETBYTES_URANDOM(128 * 1040) respectively.
>
> ...
>
> **1.2 Interface in kernel space**
>
> The kcf module provides an API for randomnes for in kernel KCF
>   consumers. It implements the functions mentioned above that are called
>   to service the read(2)/write(2) calls and also provides the interfaces
>   for kernel consumers to access the random and urandom pools.

and

> **5.0 Randomness for key generation**
>
> For asymmetric key generation inside the kernel a special
>   random_get_nzero_bytes() API is provided.It differs from
>   random_get_bytes() in two ways, first calls the
>   random_get_bytes_fips140() function which only returns once all FIPS
>   140-2 initialization has been completed. The random_get_bytes()
>   function needs to be available slightly earlier because some very
>   early kernel functions need it (particularly setup of the VM system
>   and if ZFS needs to do any writes as part of mounting the root
>   filesystem). Secondly, it ensures that no bytes in the output have the
>   0 value, those are replaced with freshly extracted additional random
>   bytes, it continues until the entire requested length is entirely made
>   up of non zero bytes.
>
> A corresponding random_get_nzero_pseduo_bytes() is also available for
>   cases were we don't want 0 bytes in other random sequences, such as
>   session keys, nonces and cookies.

The old OpenSolaris source code for the kernel functions random_get_pseudo_bytes(), random_get_bytes(), and random_get_blocking_bytes() can be found here: http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/crypto/api/kcf_random.c#1100